# Writing complexity classes in LaTeX

Tags: fonts, small-caps

Is there anyone who knows which package/style should I use to write a complexity class like this? You can see the highlighted word below, this is an all-caps word, but some letters are slightly bigger than the others. How to do this exactly in LaTeX?

[image: complexity]

Comment: You might want to have a look at the `complexity` package (even though it does not produce exactly this kind of results by default).

Comment: This is not all caps. It's merely small caps. The color can be done with `color` or better `xcolor`

Comment: @Yan: sorry for my poor english... thanks anyway...

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Use small caps.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\textsc{LogSpace}
\end{document}
```